# Confidence Levels in Statistics

Tags: statistics

I am taking an introductory statistics course, and I need help with interpreting confidence levels.

Here is the problem:

According to the Pew Research Foundation, based on a random sample of 1,001 adults, a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of adults who would ride in a driverless car is (0.45,0.51).

What is the best interpretation of this confidence level?

a)If we were to do this survey a great many times, about 95% of the resulting confidence intervals would include the true population proportion.

b)there is a 95% chance that, we were do this survey again, the population proportion would be between 0.45 and 0.51.

c)if we were to do this survey a great many times, in about 95% of the surveys the population proportion will be between 0.45 and 0.51.

d)there is a 95% chance that, we were to do this survey again, the sample proportion would be between 0.45 and 0.51.

I believe that B and D cannot be the right answer because confidence intervals refer to population parameters, and it is incorrect to say "there is a 95% chance..." So I am stuck between either choosing A or C. My professor did not really go in depth about interpreting confidence levels,and I am having trouble understanding the definition online. If you guys could help me on this problem, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you take $N$ simple random samples of size $1001$.

For each one of those samples, construct a 95% confidence interval for $p$.

Let $I_1,...,I_{N}$ be your $N$ confidence intervals and $X$ the number of intervals that contain $p$.

Then $X\sim \text{Binomial}(N,0.95)$ and $\mu_X=0.95N$

That said, the answer is $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability corresponding to confidence levels is about the ability of the process to capture the true parameter and not contingent on the interval calculated from the sample. The true parameter would either be in the arbitrary interval with probability 100% or 0%. The 95% probability in choices B and C suggests the parameter is free to vary, which is not. Therefore choices B and C are incorrect. Choice D is incorrect as confidence intervals and their associated confidence levels are used to estimate the parameter and not the sample statistic. That leaves choice A as the answer as it correctly addresses the process, the population parameter, and makes no claim about the specific interval calculated from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

The confidence interval tells you that - making certain assumptions - that 19 times out of 20 (95%) you will be correct in presuming the (usually) average is somewhere in that interval.

Put another way, making those assumptions, if people do 20 experiments, one of them will be wrong in assuming that the average is inside the interval they calculate.

Assume your goal (and the goal of 19 other people) is to estimate the average weight of a flounder in the ocean. Each of you collects and weighs 1000 flounders and averages the result - and calculates the confidence intervals.

On average, one of you will be wrong: the actual average weight will be outside your confidence intervals.

Don't forget that a large number of assumptions also get made.  Most notably, it is usually assumed that the actual distribution is normally distributed, at least for large samples (that is why I used 1000 flounders).  If smaller, you must use a Student distribution, since your estimate of the average influences your confidence intervals.

Way too much thinking goes into this at times.  With a 95% confidence level, one in twenty reported results is wrong, and the actual value lies outside the interval.  It is likely much higher, since you don't really know the data is normally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this old question was revived recently and the previously upvoted answer is incorrect, I wanted to address this problem in a separate answer.

In the frequentist interpretation of a confidence interval, it is important to remember that **interval estimates are realizations of random variables and parameters are fixed.**  The randomness is a product of the sampling process, and as such, the interval estimate is liable to change from one experiment to the next, just like how a point estimate may change with each replication of the experiment because each time, random sampling means the data obtained will be different.

Since each experiment yields a different interval estimate (in general), some of them may not actually contain the true parameter.  The confidence level is the probability that an experiment gives observed data whose interval estimate contains the true parameter--i.e., it is approximated by the idea that if you could perform many independent replications of the experiment, the proportion of interval estimates that contain the true parameter approaches the confidence level--**this is answer choice A**.

Students often ask, "if the true parameter is unknown, how do we know if the confidence interval contains the true parameter?"  The point is that we don't know.  For a single experiment from which we have calculated an interval estimate, we can't say absurdities such as "95% of the time, the true parameter is contained in the interval."  The bounds we observed are merely instances of a single experiment.  Repeating the experiment will yield new data and a new interval estimate.

The next question that students tend to ask is, "then, if we only perform the experiment once, how do we know that the confidence level really is what it says it is?"  And this is actually a good question, because the answer is that in some cases, it isn't.  In practice, what we can do is illustrate through simulation.  For instance, we might perform many experiments using simulated data from a Bernoulli model, choosing a parameter $p$ and constructing datasets of size $n$, then calculating the resulting confidence intervals and seeing how many of these datasets result in intervals that contain $p$.  And depending on *how* those intervals are calculated (because there are different ways to do it), and which $p$ you choose, you might get a proportion of intervals containing $p$ that is close to the nominal confidence level, or you might not.

A final note: all of this depends on a correct model specification.  In other words, if the experiment generates data that is not actually following the distribution you are using to construct the interval estimate, your nominal confidence level may not actually be anywhere near the actual coverage probability.